# Declare Global Array Variables in VBA-Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, global-variables

I'm trying to work with global dynamical arrays in vba excel.
the idea: I fill in information via an userform:

[image]

Then I click on the button ADD. There the "columnletter" and "name column" is saved in 2 arrays (arrBoxColumnLetters, arrBoxColumnNames). When I click on Start I want to use the information from the arrays above. But the arrays are empty...

My code:

My global variables:

```
Public i As Integer
Dim arrBoxColumnLetters() As Variant
Dim arrBoxColumnNames() As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'empty textbox
    TxtBoxExcelName.Value = ""
    TxtBoxStartRow.Value = ""
    TxtBoxTitleRowCR.Value = ""
    TxtBoxTitleRowCG.Value = ""
    TxtBoxTitleRowCB.Value = ""
    TxtBoxHeaderRowCR.Value = ""
    TxtBoxHeaderRowCG.Value = ""
    TxtBoxHeaderRowCB.Value = ""
    TxtBoxCLetter.Value = ""
    TxtBoxCName.Value = ""
    TxtBoxColumn.Value = ""
    TxtBoxTab.Value = ""
    'set focus on TxtBoxStartRow
    TxtBoxExcelName.SetFocus

    'initialize variables
    i = 0
    End Sub


    Private Sub BtnAddC_Click()
    Dim ColumnDataOri, ColumnData As String

    ReDim Preserve arrBoxColumnLetters(i + 1)
    ReDim Preserve arrBoxColumnNames(i + 1)

    ColumnDataOri = TxtBoxColumn.Value
    ColumnData = TxtBoxCLetter.Value & vbTab & vbTab & TxtBoxCName.Value
    TxtBoxColumn.Value = ColumnDataOri & vbCrLf & ColumnData

    arrBoxColumnLetters(i) = TxtBoxCLetter
    arrBoxColumnNames(i) = TxtBoxCName

    TxtBoxCLetter.Value = ""
    TxtBoxCName.Value = ""
    TxtBoxCLetter.SetFocus
    i = i + 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCancel_Click()
        Unload Me
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click()
        Call UserForm_Initialize
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSart_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim wbori As Workbook
        Dim strRGBTitleRow, strRGBHeaderRow, strFilenameOrigineel, strBoxColumnInfo As String
        Dim arrBoxColumnInfo(), arrBoxColumnLetters(), arrBoxColumnNames() As String
        Debug.Print "i=" & i
        ReDim Preserve arrBoxColumnLetters(i + 1)
        ReDim Preserve arrBoxColumnNames(i + 1)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        TxtBoxSave.Value = ""

        strRGBTitleRow = TxtBoxTitleRowCR.Value & TxtBoxTitleRowCG.Value & TxtBoxTitleRowCB.Value
        strRGBHeaderRow = TxtBoxHeaderRowCR.Value & TxtBoxHeaderRowCG.Value & TxtBoxHeaderRowCB.Value
        strFilenameOrigineel = TxtBoxExcelName.Value


        Debug.Print arrBoxColumnLetters(0)
        Debug.Print arrBoxColumnNames(0)
```

Comment: Don't use `Dim` at module-level. Use `Public` for public/global variables, and `Private` for private ones. `Dim` works exactly like `Private`, and `Public` works exactly like the obsolete/deprecated `Global` scope.

Comment: Also, anything declared in a form's code-behind is *instance* state, since a form is a class that defines an object and so its public members need to be accessed through an instance of that class. Global variables are declared in standard/procedural modules, not classes/forms/worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are rarely a good idea in VBA. However, to make sure that your variables work, declare these in a separate module, not on the form. Like this:

```
Public i As Integer
Public arrBoxColumnLetters() As Variant
Public arrBoxColumnNames() As Variant
```

Furthermore - write `Option Explicit` on the top of your code. It will let you know, that the variable `arrBoxColumnLetters` is declared twice, thus this is a bit problematic.

- [Option Explicit MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. If you say that global variables are a bad idea, how do you suggest I solve this problem? basically, I want to use the variables from the "ADD" button in the "START" prcedure.

Comment: Arrays are not allowed as "public members of object modules"

Comment: @VeVi - Avoiding global variables is an architectural problem, thus it is a bit offtopic - there is not a simple solution to it. And concerning the **Arrays are not allowed as "public members of object modules"** - what do you mean?

Comment: @VeVi seems you skipped the part where this answer says "write them in a separate module, not on the form".

Comment: Sorry, you are right, forgot the separate module part. TX!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sometimes one just needs a global **constant** array. I don't know if it's even possible in VBA